# Maven GWT plugin adding other source directories

Tags: gwt, plugins, maven

How do I add another source directory to the maven gwt compile plugin? I have some generated code that I need to include in the compile.

If I can't, what do people suggest to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you have looked into this, but you could use the [compileSourcesArtifacts](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compileSourcesArtifacts) attribute to include your generated code as an external library.  There is an article on setting this up in the [GWT Plugin Documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/library.html#Using_general_purpose_JARs_as_GWT_library).  However, this will only work if you don't need the external code to be included with your web app.

Whenever we needed to do this in the past, we used the [maven-resources-plugin's copy-resources goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to copy the source code into our main package structure, and configured the [maven-clean-plugin to remove the files](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html).  Because the gwt compile happens during the `prepare-package` phase of the [build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), you would need to copy your source files into the directory before that (we bound ours to `process-classes`).

Comment: what directory do I copy those other source files to for gwt compile to pick up?

Comment: I'd need to know a little bit more about what you're trying to do with them.  Are they views, presenters, library classes, models, or something else?

Comment: they are generated artifacts, gwtp events and actions. Turns out however that as long as I do a java compile before a gwt:compile I'm fine (It worked once I had done this). Didn't require such a complex solution.

Answer (score 2):

I put the i18n goal at the generate-resourcces phase and it worked well. It will be executed before the gwt compile.

```
    <plugins>
        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-rc1</version>
             <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <executions>
                **<execution>
                    <id>generate-i18n</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>**
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>

            <configuration>
                    <!-- your config -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because your generated output is generated in the normal source folder. 
But the question was how to add an extra source folder.