# Could I use Java 6 Annotation Processors / JSR 269 to produce code for GWT in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

Since GWT works strictly on Java *source* code, and Annotation Processors / JSR 269 generate also Java *source* code, would there be a way, in *Maven*, to have javac process the files, using the Annotation Processors, and save the *generated* Java source code somewhere, such that GWT can then use it itself, saving the work of reproducing the Annotation Processors implementation in a *GWT generator*?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822087/annotation-processor-output-in-maven), assuming the answer is still relevant, it would be best to use the [maven-processor-plugin](http://bsc-documentation-repo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven-annotation-plugin/site/index.html) to process annotations. The documentations says that you can specify an "outputDirectory". And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512638/maven-gwt-plugin-adding-other-source-directories) says you should use the *copy-resources* goal of the *maven-resources-plugin* to make the source available to GWT.

Assuming all of this is right, my question is: how do you tell Maven, that it should compile the code with javac, and run the other (maven-processor-plugin / maven-resources-plugin) plugins *before running the "GWT Maven Plugin"*? (Or would that always, for some reason, happen in that order anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to configure your Maven build. Here are a few of them:

- let the maven-compiler-plugin handle Java compilation and annotation processing, and configure it to [output the generated sources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#generatedSourcesDirectory) in addition to compiling them. Then use the build-helper-maven-plugin to [add the generated sources directory to the project sources](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) (or resources) for later consumption by the gwt-maven-plugin. That means the build-helper-maven-plugin has to run between the `compile` and `prepare-package` phases.
- use the maven-processor-plugin to run the annotation processors and output the generated sources, and make sure they're [added to the project sources](https://bsc-documentation-repo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven-annotation-plugin/site/process-mojo.html#addOutputDirectoryToCompilationSources). Then disable annotation processing for the maven-compiler-plugin using [`<proc>none</proc>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#proc).
- use the maven-compiler-plugin twice: once to run the annotation processors (with `<proc>only</proc>`), and once to compile the files (with `<proc>none</proc>`). Basically, the first execution is equivalent to using the maven-processor-plugin.

You shouldn't need to use `resources:copy-resources`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "phases" to use? Both the maven-compiler-plugin:compile and the gwt-maven-plugin:compile default to the same phase (compile), so doesn't that mean I have to tell gwt-maven-plugin:compile to run "later"(when?), to make sure maven-compiler-plugin:compile or build-helper-maven-plugin ... are done generating the code first?

Comment: `gwt:compile` [binds to the `prepare-package` phase by default](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html), and `processor:process` [binds by default to the `generate-sources` phase](https://bsc-documentation-repo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven-annotation-plugin/site/process-mojo.html) so there's no risk of "conflict". `build-helper:add-sources` for the first solution would need to run between `compiler:compiler` and `gwt:compile`; I'd probably choose [`process-classes`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

Comment: Oh sorry. When I searched, I stumbled on [this page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin-1.0/compile-mojo.html) saying it binds to "compile" but did not notice that it was for version *1.0* of gwt-maven-plugin